# How to convert Integer to drawable

Tags: java, android, image

I want to show an image in an adapter by using

`holder.myTextView.setBackground(dataSet.getImage());`

Although it says it requires a drawable but `getImage()` returns an integer, how do i convert an int to a drawable? Or is there a better way to display an image?

I have found duplicates of this question but the answers given there does not seem to work for me (using `setImageRescource`, but it is undefined and there is no suggested library that implements it)

Would really appreciate some help here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If getImage() returns an integer it is probably and R.drawable id, so in that case, you can use ContextCompat to convert it to a Drawable, like this

```
holder.myTextView.setBackground(
   ContextCompat.getDrawable(holder.myTextView.getContext(), dataSet.getImage())
);
```